# Rust RAM limited LRU cache?

Tags: rust

Is there a RAM limited LRU cache for Rust? I want to specify a 30 MB limit and when it goes over the limit it starts deleting the LRU entries.

I can find the [number of entries limited](http://contain-rs.github.io/lru-cache/lru_cache/).

Comment: What does 30MB mean? Is 30MB the total footprint of the cache + contained key/values? Or just the payload? How do you account for values which allocates? And what if some values share some parts such as with the FlyWeight pattern? Do you need to take into account the overhead from the under-use of allocated memory blocks? The overhead of the allocator data-structures? The fragmentation? The fact that the allocator itself caches memory pages before releasing them to the OS? => imagine the nightmare in creating a cache which attempts to be thorough in its memory accounting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn set_capacity(&mut self, capacity: usize)` sets the number of key value pairs the cache can hold. So if you wanted to limit it to 30MB then you would need to calculate the size of the key/value pair, and divide 30MB by the size of the key/value pair to get the capacity you should set the LRU cache to.